# Update just one index from MongoDB´s document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a Mongoose´s model on Node.js like this

```
NAME: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
ADDED_BY: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId },
ADDED_DATE: { type: Date },
STATUS: { type: String, default: 'active' }
```

I did an update of a specific document on mongo´s console, I did the next instruction:

```
db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, {NAME: "USER_ROLE"});
```

That updated the document´s NAME index, but it deleted the other indexes ( `ADDED_BY, ADDED_DATE AND STATUS` ) I don´t know what happened, how could I this query without send all params to que query?
I´m afraid, i have a collection with more than 50 indexes.

The expected result were only the NAME must be modified not all the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/index.html) operator, otherwise MongoDB will consider second argument as a replacement for your current document, try:

```
db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, { $set: {NAME: "USER_ROLE"} } )
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [$set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator that is

```
db.roles.update({NAME: "USER"}, { $set: {NAME: "USER_ROLE"}});
```